# notebook hanging on pyplot.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I'm working in iPython Notebook and am attempting to create a scatter plot.  First I import matplotlib: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.
Then I am running some very simple code to initially look at the scatter plot.  However, the plot is never displayed.  It is as if there is some setting or condition that is preventing Notebook from displaying the plot.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea as to what would cause the code to hang at this point?

Comment: Have you enabled in-line plotting?  `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: That fixed the problem.  A little further on-line checking shows I can set this in the config file.  I'll likely do that as a more permanent solution.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I added this as an `answer`

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you've enabled inline plotting via the magic function:

<strike>%matplotlib inline</strike>

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

Usually, not including this line will just lead to no plot being shown, but depending on the backend - there can be some weird results (like hanging, I suppose).

Comment: You should be using `%matplotlib notebook` instead